# Can I boot Ubuntu Mobile OS without fully wiping my phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

I really want the Ubuntu mobile OS but scared my mobile might not be able to handle it.

I have the HTC Desire 310 and it's on the Vodafone network (UK), is there way I can test run it on my phone without actually replacing my Android OS entirely and will it be able to connect via data transfer (so not WiFi)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally for non-Nexus devices, that's a no. There are no official images or semi offical ports with such functionality.

The least invasive installation was a [DualBoot installation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) released for the Nexus 4. It consisted basically of:

- A custom recovery image used to boot Ubuntu
- "The data partition contains the Ubuntu system under /data/ubuntu/"

So the installer script would set this up for you and you could still use your Android without wiping. It may still work with recent combinations of Ubuntu and Android releases, but I havent testet this as I sold my Nexus 4.